# Continuous Syntax Error with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to make a conversion program with Python on my Raspberry Pi. For some reason, when ever I try to run the code, it gets through the first 6 lines with no errors, and then errors out on every line after that. I am using Python 3, and I see no reason why it would be doing this.

```
#Defining Conversion Function
def convert():
    #Millimeter Conversions
    #It gets through this line of code here
    unit = input('Please enter your unit conversion in the form unit1:unit2 (ex. cm:in)'.lower()
#Then errors out here
    number = input('Please enter your first number')

    if unit == 'mm:cm':
        newnumber = float(number) / 10
        print (newnumber)
    elif unit == 'mm:dm':
        newnumber = float(number) / 100
        print (newnumber)
    elif unit == 'mm:m':
        newnumber = float(number) / 1000
        print (newnumber)
    elif unit == 'mm:dkm':
        newnumber = float(number) / 10000
        print (newnumber)
    elif unit == 'mm:hm':
        newnumber = float(number) / 100000
        print (newnumber)
    elif unit == 'mm:km':
            newnumber = float(number) / 1000000
            print (newnumber)

    #Centimeter Conversions    
    if unit == 'cm:mm':
        newnumber = float(number) * 10
        print(newnumber)
    elif unit == 'cm:dm':
        newnumber = float(number) / 10
        print (newnumber)
    elif unit == 'cm:m':
        newnumber = float(number) / 100
        print (newnumber)
    elif unit == 'cm:dkm':
        newnumber = float(number) / 1000
        print (newnumber)
    elif unit == 'cm:hm':
        newnumber = float(number) / 10000
        print (newnumber)
    elif unit == 'cm:km':
        newnumber = float(number) / 100000
        print (newnumber)

#Defining the Scientific Notation Function
def sn():
    sn = input ('Pease enter you Scientific Notation string')
    print ('%0.10f' % x)
```

Comment: Shouldn't `unit = input(...); number =  input(...)` be indented?

Comment: Please fix your indentation and add what the full traceback

Comment: Sorry, for some reason it did not indent properly on here. I had in indented on the actual script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a missing `)` at unit initialization before `lower()`. Should be like this:

```
unit = input('Please enter your unit conversion in the form unit1:unit2 (ex. cm:in)').lower()
```